# How to get compile time in clang?

Tags: c, time, compilation, clang

When compiling with `gcc` I used `time` to get compile time.

```
time gcc main.c && ./a.out
```

when trying to do the similar thing in `clang` I can't get the result

```
clang -time main.c && ./a.out
```

gives me a waring:

> clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-time'

probably my approach is false, so please help me find compile time using clang

Comment: Do you mean `time gcc main.c`?

Comment: yes exactly, sorry for that

Comment: Then it's exactly the same. You can put any command after `time`.

Comment: Great, it worked, thanks a lot. Although it is approximately 1,5 times slower than gcc for some reason, but this isn't not my concern anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither `gcc time …` nor `clang -time …` make any sense. You're looking for the `time` shell command (or shell keyword), which you can put before any command.

```
time gcc main.c && ./a.out
time clang main.c && ./a.out
```

This is assuming bash or a similar shell such as zsh or ksh (or even fish).

Comment: @Barmar Any shell in a unix-like environment. Not on a basic Windows.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I've been looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Try `clang main.c -ftime-report`

Comment: Would be nice if you explain it a bit further